# Schema with relationship is not saved in db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, crud, database-schema

I am creating an api with the basic operations crud, I am using mongodb and i have 1 schema which requires information from another schema, i made the relationship in this way, in the first shema i have this.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const geographicalAreaSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('GeographicalArea', geographicalAreaSchema);
```

Second schema with the reference

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const zooSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    nit: { type: String, required: true },
    geographicalArea: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "GeographicalArea" }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Zoo', zooSchema);
```

In the controller have this code to save the new zoo

```
const zoo = require('../models/zoo');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const GeographicalArea = mongoose.model('GeographicalArea');
const zooController = {};

zooController.createZoo = async(req, res) => {
    const saveZoo = new zoo({
        name: req.body.name,
        nit: req.body.nit,
        geographicalAreaName: req.body.geographicalArea.name //this item have data
    });
    await saveZoo.save()
    res.json({
        'status': 'Zoo Save'
    })
};

module.exports = zooController;
```

This is the router file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const zoo = require('../controllers/zoo.controller');

router.post('/', zoo.createZoo)

module.exports = router;
```

This is the index file

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const app = express();

const { mongoose } = require('./database');

//Settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//Middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

//Routes
app.use('/api/geographicalArea', require('./routes/geographicalArea.routes'));
app.use('/api/zoo', require('./routes/zoo.routes'));

//Starting server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server on port', app.get('port'))
})
```

When I make a post request from postman like this

[image: postman]

I see if req brings the data

[image]

And I debug to verify that the data is saved correctly, the field of geographicalArea returns undefined

[image]

**I don't know why this attribute goes undefined**

Comment: I think the issue is that you are referencing name but you need to use _id.try req.body.geographicalArea._id.

Comment: Also your key in object is also wrong. try geographicalArea instend of geographicalAreaName

Comment: Instead of **`Schema.ObjectId`** in `geographicalArea` field , use **`Schema.Types.ObjectId`**.

Comment: @RajPurohit If I change geographicalArea instend of geographicalAreaName, the application crashes, returning this error `ValidationError: Zoo validation failed: geographicalArea: Cast to ObjectID failed for 
value "Asia" at path "geographicalArea"`

Comment: @metalHeadDev thanks for the answer, but i have the same issue,the data arrives but cannot store in the constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the issue by sending from postman only the geographicalArea id to which i want to relate to the zoo, this way I get the object with all the information of this.

Send data

[image]

```
    zooController.createZoo = async(req, res) => {
    const saveZoo = new zoo({
        name: req.body.name,
        nit: req.body.nit,
        geographicalArea: req.body.geographicalArea
    });
    await saveZoo.save()
    res.json({
        'status': 'Zoo Save'
    })
};
```

I verify that I get the data

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

```js
const zoo = require('../models/zoo')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const GeographicalArea = mongoose.model('GeographicalArea')
const zooController = {}

zooController.createZoo: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const zooInfo = {
        name: req.body.name,
        nit: req.body.nit,
        geographicalAreaName: req.body.geographicalArea.name
      }
      const zooSave = await zoo.create(zooInfo)
      console.log(zooInfo)
      zooSave.save()
      res.json({ status: "zoo saved "})
     } catch(error) {
       res.json({ error })
    }
  }
```

Comment: in this case the const zooInfo have the data of `req.body.geographicalArea.name` but when it gets to the line `const zooSave = await zoo.create (zooInfo)`
zooSave keep returning 
**geographicalArea: undefined**. At this point i think the issue is in the schema

Comment: I've edited the answer. What's the value of  `console.log(zooInfo)` above?

Comment: this is the value `{ name: 'Test22', nit: 'nitTest', geographicalAreaName: 'Asia' }` but `zoo.create(zooInfo)` the attribute **geographicalArea:undefined**

Comment: the attribute **geographicalArea** still returning undefined